# can i write complex queries in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have to retrieve particular attribute from an asset like **select name from employeetable**.is it possible to fetch particular attribute in hyperledger composer

Comment: It's not possible to do this in composer at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here the official documentation

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/query-language

And the specific example

```
query findEmployee{
    description: "Select employee based on the name"
    statement:
        SELECT org.example.Employee
            WHERE (firstName == _$nameParam)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In composer rest server, you can use API with filter `fields`.
Such as `{"fields": ["name", "description"]"}`
It will return only those fields instead of full objects.

Reference: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/query
It said only `where` is currently support, but `fields` can be used as well.